# Combined Stack Exchange Flair broken?

Tags: support, bug, combined-flair

This is the first time I've tried to play with the flair, seems to be working well for Stack Overflow, but I think the image may be down for the combined Stack Exchange version. It looks like I'm just getting the alternate text.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is anyone else having this problem at the moment? Am I the only one who is seeing the second flair below incorrectly?

Just to check to see if I'm seeing something different here:

In Chrome:

[image]

In Firefox:

[image]

[image: profile for apaul34208 at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

[image: profile for apaul34208 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

I tried to look at the [image directly](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2203510.png) and got the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" page

**Update:** as of today 8/24/2013 the problem is no longer occurring. To who ever fixed it, thank you.

Comment: It works for me using latest Chrome.

Comment: I See it, too. (I'm assuming your flair in the post above is the 'actual' flair itself?)

Comment: @AndrewBarber checked in Firefox v23, and Chrome v28, I can see the SO version, but not the SE version. What gives?

Comment: What do you get if you load the flair directly? And can you use something like Fiddler to see what the response is? http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2203510.png

Comment: @AndrewBarber I clicked the link you provided and got the "oops something bad happened" page

Comment: Oh, now that's interesting. So you got an error page from the Stack Exchange site, then.

Comment: @AndrewBarber yup

Comment: Gotcha. I would add that info to the question, too. Makes it more clear it's a server-side issue.

Comment: @AndrewBarber so just to be clear can you see both flairs in the question?

Comment: Yup; I see your Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange flair both. I even just tried loading it with junk query string data to make sure.

Comment: I'm seeing both fine here too.

Comment: @Undo it's still broken on my end, I tried all the usual suspects, but no luck

Comment: @apaul34208 Work firewall?

Comment: @Undo nope... cleared the cache, tried different browsers, tried the image directly... The error page seems to suggest it's a back-end problem, but it doesn't make sense that I would be the only one effected

Comment: @apaul34208 I'm having the exact same problem, my flair looks like your picture on all site's but other's flair seems to be working.

Comment: @somethingSomething Probably need to open a new question, feel free to link to this one if it helps.

Comment: @apaul34208 Ok,yes, I'll give some time, I've only seen this on one of my systems, in Firefox, haven't tried other browser. If it doesn't go away, I'll open a new question.