# Combined Stack Exchange flair not displaying

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair, combined-flair

It seems that the [Combined Stack Exchange user flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair) isn't displaying properly on profile pages. When I am logged in, the page displays as follows.

[image: User flair page]

I've been able to recreate the issue in multiple browsers, including [Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loUEc.png), [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avyga.png), and [Safari (iOS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avyga.png).

It's worth noting this issue [was previously reported in 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194206/351462), but was supposedly fixed.

Comment: Btw, Without login, it shows flair of random users (combined flair is empty).

Comment: That explains a few things. Though my flair should still be showing up, since I have 200+ flair on 3 SE sites.

Comment: That combined flair link will redirect to the logged in user's flair For your's you need to insert your user id and name. I can see your flair OK (I can browse to the link because I'm mod on SO, though I won't post the link).

Comment: @ChrisF That's strange. When I check the user flair page while logged in, [the page displays like this](http://i.imgur.com/ovM6CSH.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this post was made, the issue appears to have been fixed.

Mark this one as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[image]